# Switching buffers in Vim

Tags: vim, emacs

I've recently switched from Emacs to Vim, so this may just be me completely misunderstanding how Vim works.

I've opened a file in Vim and make some changes but don't save them. I then use `:e otherfile` to open a second file, and make some changes to that. Again, without saving the changes, I'd like to go back to the first buffer. I'm using `:bn` for that, but when I do I get `E37: No write since last change ...`. If I do `:bn!` then I can change back to the first buffer. From the first buffer I can change back to the second buffer with a straight `:bn`, but I have to do `:bn!` to go from the second buffer to the first every time.

I've got `set bufhidden=hide` in my vimrc, but if I run `:set bufhidden?` in Vim I get `bufhidden=`. Is that the problem maybe?

**Edit:** I've narrowed the problem down a bit. In the first file, `:set bufhidden?` returns `bufhidden=hide`, but in the second file, it returns `bufhidden=`. What's up with that? Am I missing something fundamental about Vim buffers here?

**Edit2:** Ok, it seems like `set bufhidden=hide` only applies to the first buffer opened. It needs to be explicitly called in subsequent buffers. I must be completely missing the point here, because this doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Do you still have the problem. Have you found how to solved the problem or considered accepting an answer that solves your problem (if any)?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I was just being an idiot. I didn't want `set bufhidden=hide` in my vimrc - that's just for a single buffer. Now that I've changed it to `set hidden` everything works as I felt it should.

Comment: Could you add this as your accepted answer, since it worked for you?